# Slide relatively positioned images in/out with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to use jQuery UI's slide effect on images inside a div. I'm attempting to make it appear that the images are sliding behind a cut-out in the page and in order to get the inset box shadow to appear I am using relative positioning for the images.

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746017/jquery-smooth-sliding-gallery/8747598#8747598) makes it seem that the relative positioning has something to do with why the slide effect is not working.

I noticed that this works (but doesn't animate the transition):

```
$images.css("left", -150);
```

But this does not:

```
$images.show("slide", { direction: "left", distance: "150px" });
```

Is there an easy jQuery UI or CSS fix that can be made here? I'm also not wholly committed to using jQuery UI either, if there's a simpler alternative.

My primary goal has been to keep the HTML as-is though. If I have to make concessions then I will, but I like the clean list of images in a div and would prefer to keep the HTML that way if I can.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ygg3tpa/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't mind not having an animation on IE 9 a simple solution would be to add a css transition for the left property

```
.image {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */
          transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
}
```

Comment: This is pretty slick. The first time I click "Left" the transition effect does not happen. If I click "Right" first though, things seem to work. Should I explicitly call `$images.css("left", -150);` when the page loads to workaround this or is there a better solution?

Comment: The transition CSS is specifically referencing specifically 'left'.  The animation may be using a negative 'right' value at first so adding a transition for 'right' might have it work for both calls.  You can also have multiple properties defined in one transition rule. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Unfortunately adding a "right" to the transition didn't affect the first click. No problem though, explicitly calling `$images.css("left", 0)` causes that oddity to go away and I can live with that.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has its own slide effect, without using the UI. As well, you can use it's animate effect to get some cool effects too.

```
$(selector).slideDown(speed,callback);
$(selector).slideUp(speed,callback);
$(selector).slideToggle(speed,callback);
```

[More info on slide](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp)

```
$(selector).animate({params},speed,callback);
```

[More info on animate](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)

Comment: `$images.animate({"left": "-150px"});` does the trick but I like the CSS approach offered by Nate *slightly* more. I might revisit this approach if I end up needing a callback though!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS 'left' property will do little to a relatively positioned element - [MDN Reference for 'left' property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left).  You might want to try animating margin-left.

```
$images.animate({marginLeft: '+=500px'}, 5000);
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about the "+=" syntax. While I'm going with the CSS approach, I'll definitely incorporate that nugget into the code. Thanks!